# How to find the JPG quality?

Tags: windows, metadata, jpeg, gimp

When I save a JPG file with GIMP, I can adjust the quality I save it at, from 0-100 (I use 89). It seems like I've used an app to see what this number was on saved file but if I did I can't for the life of me figure out what it was. Any suggestions as to what to use?

Comment: Just to make sure that it is known: the quality setting of different applications is not comparable, in general: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-5.html. Both GIMP and ImageMagick should use the IJG quality scale, though.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

<strike>Once saved, you cannot tell the quality anymore.</strike>

(Setting the quality while saving just tells the software how much loss you find acceptable, but once saved: what's lost is lost. You'd need a human to say if something looks nice.)

Hmmm, I guess I was wrong. I still think the above is correct, but [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)'s [`identify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) proves me wrong?

```
identify -verbose myimage.jpg

Image: myimage.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 358x240+0+0
  Resolution: 300x300
  [...]
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 90
  Orientation: Undefined
  [...]
```

I don't know how the image in my test was saved, but it does not have any EXIF data. Could the quality still be stored in the image?

Comment: Can't you experiment converting to different qualities? I find it hard to believe, unless ImageMagick stores some private data in the jpg (so this might not work with other packages).

Comment: Interesting. I'll wait to see how this pans out.

Comment: +1 Yes imagemagick works.  I can repeatedly change the jpeg quality and use identify to see the change.  This works if I use convert (another imagemagick untility)  or another tool like MS Photo Editor.

Comment: ImageMagick is doing something different. It gives an estimate, rather than reading what your original software did. Your original, now-crossed-out, answer is really more correct. See @sleske's answer.

Comment: **ImageMagick returns a quality assessment number, but that doesn't mean it's correct.** See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/jpeg-faq/part1/section-5.html from the jpeg creators themselves, and https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88167/is-it-possible-to-find-out-what-compression-ratio-was-used-for-a-particular-jpeg

Answer (score 37):

To add to Arjan's answer:

ImageMagick's `identify` appears to actually look inside the JPEG image to guess the quality setting used to encode it.

[ImageMagick's source code (cheer for free software  :-)) contains the lines](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/05d2ff7ebf21f659f5b11e45afb294e152f4330c/coders/jpeg.c#L818):

```
/*
  Determine the JPEG compression quality from the quantization tables.
*/
sum=0;
for (i=0; i < NUM_QUANT_TBLS; i++)
{
  if (jpeg_info.quant_tbl_ptrs[i] != NULL)
    for (j=0; j < DCTSIZE2; j++)
      sum+=jpeg_info.quant_tbl_ptrs[i]->quantval[j];
```

(`coders/jpeg.c`, line 843ff. in my recent version of ImageMagick's source code).

I don't know enough about JPEG to really understand, but it appears to do something like described in this article:

[*Determine the JPEG quality factor by using Visual C# .NET*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324790) (link dead as of Januar 2018; [copy on archive.org from 2015](https://web.archive.org/web/20150328083839/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324790))

So yes, `identify` can actually determine the quality setting of a JPEG just from the compressed file alone (though the result may not always be completely accurate).

Comment: Whoa. Very nice of you to check the source code. Cool.

Comment: @Nathaniel, can you please select this answer as being the accepted one, instead of mine? Thanks! (I cannot delete mine as long as it's accepted.)

Comment: It is searching for the JPEG quantization table that best accounts for how the compressed bitstream looks.

Comment: Constants (jpeglib.h): `NUM_QUANT_TBLS` = `4`. `DCTSIZE2` = `64`. `quantval[i]` just gets the number at given position.

Answer (score 12):

As Arjan metioned `identify -verbose myimage.jpg` will do it. As imagemagick is a CLI tool, it may be useful for scripting. The approach `identify -verbose myimage.jpg | grep ...` is preety slow. I recommend using IM like this

```
identify -format '%Q' myimage.jpg
```

It is massively faster.

Answer (score 4):

[JPEGsnoop](https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/JPEGsnoop) is a nice alternative to ImageMagick's `identify`. The download is quite small and is available in portable format.

After processing a jpg, you will find the "Approx quality factor" under the DQT marker.

Answer (score 2):

Picasa 3 has the properties pane which shows the jpeg quality but it is an abandonware at the moment.
[image: Picasa 3 Dick Masterson]

Comment: http://www.filehorse.com/download-picasa/

Answer (score 1):

With [ImageMagick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) library it's easy:

```
Image magick_image( pathname );
size_t compressionFactor = magick_image.quality(); // 0..100
```