# Verify image quality using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, image-conversion

We are converting group 4 TIFF images to PNG; this may deteriorate the quality.

Is there any way to automate image quality verification using ImageMagick?

Comment: What do you mean by "validation of image quality check"? Verifying if a image is 'of good quality' (for a specific purpose) or not can be a very complex image processing problem.

Comment: Isn't PNG supposed [to be lossless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)? So, other than the image size, the quality should not go worse? For JPG, see [How to find the JPG quality?](http://superuser.com/questions/62730/how-to-find-the-jpg-quality) Maybe it can do the same for PNG.

Comment: @Arjan being that PNG files are lossless, the idea of 'quality' doesn't exist.

Comment: I think so too, @Renan, but just to be sure: I was referring to image *dimensions* (number of pixels) when referring to "size". (But I admit I was not very clear in that respect.)

Comment: @Arjan I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

As said in a comment, PNG files are [lossless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics), so you can't talk about a "loss of quality".

The closest that PNG has to a "quality" is the compression level, which relates only to [file size](http://newsgroup.xnview.com/viewtopic.php?t=4101) (a trade-off between file size and time needed to decode the image), not to image quality.

Comment: PNG does support 8 bit in which case one would have dithering or color approximation, banding etc. So long as the OP chooses PNG-24, this isn't an issue. (or rather, so long as the color pallette is not altered)